Zariski tangent space of an infinite product of Lie groups
I am trying to understand the proof of the following lemma in Maret's Character varieties:

Lemma 2.3.2. The Zariski tangent space to $G^\Gamma$ at any point identifies with $\mathfrak g^\Gamma$.

Here, $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated group, $G$ is a Lie group, and $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. The definition of the locally ringed space $G^\Gamma$ is written right above the lemma in the paper. The paper only gives a brief proof but I want to understand it in full detail.
I think the full proof should be as follows. Let $f\in G^\Gamma$, which is a function $\Gamma\to G$. The goal is to construct a pair of $\mathbb R$-vector-space-isomorphisms between $T_f\left(G^\Gamma\right)$ and $\mathfrak g^\Gamma\left(=\prod_{x\in\Gamma}(T_1G)\right)$. I will define them as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
T_f\left(G^\Gamma\right) & \xrightarrow{F} & \prod_{x\in\Gamma}\left(T_{f(x)}G\right) & \xrightarrow{G} & \prod_{x\in\Gamma}\left(T_1G\right) \\
u & \mapsto & (d\pi_x(u))_{x\in\Gamma} & \mapsto & \left(dR_{f(x)^{-1}}(d\pi_x(u))\right)_{x\in\Gamma}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
T_f\left(G^\Gamma\right) & \xleftarrow{H} & \prod_{x\in\Gamma}(T_1G) \\
d\alpha\left(\frac{d}{dt}|_0\right) & \leftarrow\!\shortmid & (u(x))_{x\in\Gamma}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
where $\pi_x:G^\Gamma\to G,\,\phi\mapsto\phi(x)$ is the projection, $R_h:G\to G,\,g\mapsto gh$ is the right-translation, and $\alpha:\mathbb R\to G^\Gamma,\,t\mapsto(\exp(t\cdot u(x))\cdot f(x))_{x\in\Gamma}$. I chekced that $F,G,H$ are all well-defined $\mathbb R$-linear maps, and that $G\circ F\circ H$ is the identity-map. The only thing left to check is that $H\circ G\circ F$ is the identity-map, but I was not able to do this.
